# Using Maple to find the sequence of row operations to calculate the inverse of a matrix

Tags: matrices, maple, gaussian-elimination

One way to find the inverse of a matrix is going through a sequence of row operations ([**Gauss-Jordan Elimination**](http://www.mathportal.org/linear-algebra/matrices/gauss-jordan.php)).

I want Maple to output the necessary sequence [*by "sequence", I mean the set of operations and the order in which they must be applied*] of such operations, given a square matrix.

Is there a way I can have Maple to do it for me?

Comment: Maple has commands for the basic row operations, and has a command to get the final form, but for the steps, you would have to choose the operations yourself, one at a time. Of course you could write a little Maple program to choose the steps and display the results, one step at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Maple has a Student:-LinearAlgebra package that includes a couple elimination tutors that can show all the steps interactively.  e.g.

```
with(Student:-LinearAlgebra):
M := <<1,2,0>|<2,3,2>|<0,2,1>|<3,5,5>>;
GaussJordanEliminationTutor( M );
```